# Problem about the set of relatively prime integers

Tags: number-theory

Find the least positive integer $n$ such that any set of $n$ pairwise relatively prime integers greater than $1$ and less than $2005$ contains at least one prime number.

**My solution:** Let's reformulate our problem: Find the biggest $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ such that exists the set of $n_0$ pairwise relatively prime integers $>1$ and $<2005$ contains no prime numbers. If we find that number $n_0$ then the number $n=n_0+1$ is answer to our initial stated problem.

Since $k=\pi(2005)=304$ where $\pi(x)$ - the number of prime less than $x$. Let's consider the set $A=\{p_1^2, p_2^2, \dots, p_{k}^2\}$ and it is obvious that this set consists of relatively prime numbers and does not containt prime number. But if we add one more number, namely $q$ from interval $(1,2005)$ then this $q$ will imply the following: $\text{gcd}(q, p_j)=p_j>1$.

Hence the biggest number is $n=304+1=305$.

However, the answer in the book is 15.

What is wrong with my reasoning?

**EDIT:** Let's take the set $A=\{p_1^2,p_2^2, \dots, p_{14}^2\}$ where $p_{14}=43$ and wee see that this set has relatively prime integers $>1$ and $<2005$ and contains no prime number. Hence $n_0\geqslant 14$. Let's take the set of $15$ numbers $\{a_1, a_2, \dots, a_{15}\}$ and let $q_i$ the least prime factor of $a_i$ and it's easy to see that sequence $\{q_1, q_2, \dots, q_{15}\}$ is pairwise distinct. Also $\hat{q}=\max q_{i} \geqslant p_{15}=47$. Let $\hat{a}$ the number in sequence $\{a_1, a_2, \dots, a_{15}\}$ which corresponds to $\hat{q}$. Then $\dfrac{\hat{a}}{\hat{q}}$ is divisible by some prime number greater or equal that $\hat{q}$. Thus $\hat{a}\geqslant \hat{q}^2 \geqslant 47^2=2209>2005$. We get contradiction. Hence $n_0=14$.

So desired answer to our initial problem is $14+1=15$. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: The squares of those primes are not all less than $2005$.

Comment: Note:  your argument appears to work perfectly if you apply it to $\sqrt {2005}$.  I think, though, that you need a line or two to explain why your set is maximal.

Comment: Hmm. I knew that $p_{304}<2005$ but I did not pay attention to it's square which is certainly greater than 2005. Nice comment. Plus for it!

Comment: Once you rectify this, your argument is sound, since $\pi(\lfloor \sqrt{2005}\rfloor) + 1 = 14 + 1 = 15$.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг, Yes I got it.

Comment: @lulu, I have edited my answer. Could you take a look, please? Is it correct?

Comment: Your reasoning is sound.  My one  objection is that you don't address the possibility that someone could construct a larger collection in some different way.  this is not difficult to argue:  suppose I have $16$ relatively prime numbers less than $2005$ (none of them prime).  Other than $1$, each of them must be divisible by at least two primes which are distinct from any primes dividing anything else on the list (they may coincide with each other though).  Clearly one of those, at least, must be less than $\sqrt {2005}$ and there are only $14$ of those, a contradiction.

Comment: In you last post you state it is possible that $n_0$ could be equal $16$, right? What about $17, 18$?

Comment: @lulu, I think that my above reasoning for $15$ numbers can be easily applied to $16+$ numbers, right?

Comment: If you have a collection of more than $16$ then you obviously have a collection of $16$.

Comment: @lulu, 1) you last sentence seems unclear to me. What does it mean? 2) Are you agree that my above reasoning applicable to 16 collection?

Comment: Maybe I missed part of your argument.  Why is it clear that $\hat q≥p_{15}$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68209/discussion-between-rfz-and-lulu).